# Gson from json response return null array list

Tags: java, json, jakarta-ee, gson

hi I am working on parsing json from gson and i have a parsing probleme when i parse it return null

I tried with the typeToken it didn't work i printed the data it shows correctly the json but when i try to parse it it shows a null list

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Skill>>(){}.getType();

    String data = "[" +
            "{\"SkillName\":\"Jee\"}," +
            "{\"SkillName\":\"Java\"}," +
            "{\"SkillName\":\"Spring\"}," +
            "{\"SkillName\":\"Symfony\"}," +
            "{\"SkillName\":\"C++\"}," +
            "{\"SkillName\":\"putain\"}]";
    System.out.println(data);

    List<Skill> yourClassList = new Gson().fromJson(data, listType);
    System.out.println(yourClassList);
}
```

I go those results

```
[{"SkillName":"Jee"},{"SkillName":"Java"},{"SkillName":"Spring"}{"SkillName":"Symfony"},{"SkillName":"C++"},{"SkillName":"putain"}]
[Skill [skillId=0, skillName=null], Skill [skillId=0, skillName=null], Skill [skillId=0, skillName=null], Skill [skillId=0, skillName=null], Skill [skillId=0, skillName=null], Skill [skillId=0, skillName=null]][Skill [skillId=0, skillName=null], Skill [skillId=0, skillName=null], Skill [skillId=0, skillName=null], Skill [skillId=0, skillName=null], Skill[skillId=0, skillName=null], Skill [skillId=0, skillName=null]]
```

Comment: Please check whether the variables declared in your class and json are matching exactly (alphabet to alphabet) and the order in which they are present in json and declared in class are same.

Comment: Can you share your skill class?

Comment: thank you very much  @VikasAgarwal   i changed skilName by SkillName